# Why I have a .bashrc.dpkg-dist file?

Tags: linux-mint, bashrc

I just install Linux Mint Debian Edition, and in my home there is a `.bashrc.dpkg-dist` file instead of Ye old `.bashrc`

Why?

Can I move it to `.bashrc`?, Should I edit a new `.bashrc` file or the `.bashrc.dpkg-dist` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just move it to `.bashrc` (`mv ~/.bashrc.dpkg-dist ~/.bashrc`) or use one from a previous installation. It's probably from a update of bash in Linux Mint Debian Edition that replaced the default `.bashrc` either before you performed your installation or by installing updates.

I'm on LMDE and also have a `.bashrc.dpkg-dist` in the `/etc/skel` directory.

You can find more information on Debian configuration files [here](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/).